# Visualise JSON elements using some math

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**EDIT**: I'm still not there yet. I have placed a bounty on this question because I could really do with the answer. I have made do with the idea of elements that represent the planets that don't revolve around the center. Because of this, you can skip steps 1 & 2 and go straight to 3 to try to help me out.

**ORIGINAL**: I am working on a fun little project. It's a solar system in which planets revolve around the sun. I consider it a simulation that's consistent of 3 big steps.

*First step:* create a functional revolving Solar system with the 8 planets.

*Second step:* create a function that adds new planets revolving around the same sun, with the click of a button with its specifics being based randomly (ie: distance from the sun, color of the planet, size of the planet, etc.)

I'm on the third step, and I don't want things to be random anymore. The third step is for me by far the hardest one for me because I have little experience with JSON. I have data from all the exoplanets beyond our solar system from the NASA website, and I want to add these individal objects (planets) into the simulation with the function that adds the objects.

**My question to you is:** How would my code need to look to have each individual record you see here in the JSON array in my code, as an element that's placed away from the black speck on the center of the screen (see the fiddle) in a random angle, this so it's not all aligned the same. In the end, I wish to have thousands of small specks that represent planets shown on the screen, where the black speck currently only visible, is to be the sun.

This is because there are thousands of planets like this in my JSON file, and I want to see them all revolve with their respective distance from the sun "Distance [pc]", their respective size "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]". Of course, the science wouldn't need to be accurate, but it should somewhat be. For example, the planet with the greatest Distance [pc] (distance in parsec) needs to be the farthest away, but still be able to be seen on the screen, even if it's just a little speck.

Now I am aware that some math is involved to appropiately position each planet based on the distance property, because they are listed as distance in parsec, some conversion method would be in order to place them all on the same screen, while they're still visible.

This is my code, but not all of it. To see all of it, click the link posted under this code.

```
        //this is an array that holds all of the json data
           var arr=   [
                 {
                   "rowid": 1,
               "Host name": "11 Com",
               "Number of Planets in System": 1,
               "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 19.4,
               "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": null,
               "Planet Density [g": {
                  "cm**3]": null
               },
               "Distance [pc]": 110.62,
               "Effective Temperature [K]": 4742,
               "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
            },
             {
               "rowid": 2,
               "Host name": "11 UMi",
               "Number of Planets in System": 1,
               "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 10.5,
               "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": null,
               "Planet Density [g": {
                  "cm**3]": null
               },
               "Distance [pc]": 119.47,
               "Effective Temperature [K]": 4340,
               "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
            },
             {
               "rowid": 3,
               "Host name": "14 And",
               "Number of Planets in System": 1,
               "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 4.8,
               "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": null,
               "Planet Density [g": {
                  "cm**3]": null
               },
               "Distance [pc]": 76.39,
               "Effective Temperature [K]": 4813,
               "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
            },
             {
               "rowid": 4,
               "Host name": "14 Her",
               "Number of Planets in System": 1,
               "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 4.64,
               "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": null,
               "Planet Density [g": {
                  "cm**3]": null
               },
               "Distance [pc]": 18.15,
               "Effective Temperature [K]": 5311,
               "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
            }];

//these variables hold specific properties
    var distance;
    var planetRadius;
    var rowid;
    var hostName;

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

       rowid= arr[i]["rowid"];
       distance= arr[i]["Distance [pc]"];
       hostName= arr[i]["Host name"];
       planetRadius=arr[i]["Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]"];//This is the idea how we should access the json objects, as your operations are not clear to us just I'm giving the idea
      // Do what ever you want with  individual object
           if(planetRadius !== null){
               // If planet radius not null do whatever you want.
            }
    }
```

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50dj9cpq/2/) holds the essential code. **Note:** this link has all of the 3000+ planets in the code, so it might act up on you in terms of loading. Simply type in 1 instead of 2 in the URL to go to the draft in which there are just a few examples of hte planets, if your browser is acting up on you.

Comment: What you wanna do with each object from the array of object??

Comment: I mean do you wanna place somewhere or need to do some operation

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear, but I want to have each object's size and distance from the sun element be based on "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]" (if a value is not null) and "Distance [pc]".  

Ooh I just realised the examples I gave just happened to be all null. This represents only like 10% of all the planets in the array.  I'll make an edit about that.

Comment: It seems like you want to add a new svg `<circle>` object for each new planet.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give this a try:

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50dj9cpq/4/).  Distance is logarithmic so that all the planets fit on the screen.

```
var arr=   [
     {
       "rowid": 1,
       "Host name": "11 Com",
       "Number of Planets in System": 1,
       "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 19.4,
       "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": null,
       "Planet Density [g": {
          "cm**3]": null
       },
       "Distance [pc]": 110.62,
       "Effective Temperature [K]": 4742,
       "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
    },
     {
       "rowid": 2,
       "Host name": "11 UMi",
       "Number of Planets in System": 1,
       "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 10.5,
       "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": null,
       "Planet Density [g": {
          "cm**3]": null
       },
       "Distance [pc]": 119.47,
       "Effective Temperature [K]": 4340,
       "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
    },
     {
       "rowid": 3,
       "Host name": "14 And",
       "Number of Planets in System": 1,
       "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 4.8,
       "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": null,
       "Planet Density [g": {
          "cm**3]": null
       },
       "Distance [pc]": 76.39,
       "Effective Temperature [K]": 4813,
       "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
    },
     {
       "rowid": 4,
       "Host name": "14 Her",
       "Number of Planets in System": 1,
       "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 4.64,
       "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": null,
       "Planet Density [g": {
          "cm**3]": null
       },
       "Distance [pc]": 18.15,
       "Effective Temperature [K]": 5311,
       "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
    }];
var distance;
var planetRadius;
var rowid;
var hostName;


var svg=document.getElementById("Layer_1");
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

   rowid= arr[i]["rowid"];
   distance= arr[i]["Distance [pc]"];
   hostName= arr[i]["Host name"];
   planetRadius=arr[i]["Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]"];//This is the idea how we should access the json objects, as your operations are not clear to us just I'm giving the idea
  // Do what ever you want with  individual object
       if(planetRadius !== null){
           // If planet radius not null do whatever you want.
           var circle=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","circle");
           circle.setAttribute("class","fillblack");
           circle.setAttribute("cx","0");
           circle.setAttribute("cy","0");
           circle.setAttribute("r",planetRadius.toString());
           var logDist=Math.log(distance+1)*50;
           var angle=0; // change this based on the current time, if you would like an animation
           circle.setAttribute("transform","translate(500 300.8) rotate("+angle+") translate("+logDist+")");
           svg.appendChild(circle);
        }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    // do your animations here
});
```

If you want, you can add an animation by changing the `angle` variable in the transform based on the current time.  SVG transforms make the math pretty simple as you can concatenate transforms.

However, I doubt that 3000+ planets can be animated at 60 fps with `<svg>` with current computers.  If you want a smooth animation, you might want to look at `<canvas>`.

**EDIT:** It is decently smooth, but doesn't look like 60 fps to me. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50dj9cpq/5/).

Answer (score 0):

If you need each individual object to perform the operations use the for loop.

```
     var arr=   [
         {
           "rowid": 1,
           "Host name": "11 Com",
           "Number of Planets in System": 1,
           "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 19.4,
           "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": null,
           "Planet Density [g": {
              "cm**3]": null
           },
           "Distance [pc]": 110.62,
           "Effective Temperature [K]": 4742,
           "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
        },
         {
           "rowid": 2,
           "Host name": "11 UMi",
           "Number of Planets in System": 1,
           "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 10.5,
           "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": null,
           "Planet Density [g": {
              "cm**3]": null
           },
           "Distance [pc]": 119.47,
           "Effective Temperature [K]": 4340,
           "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
        },
         {
           "rowid": 3,
           "Host name": "14 And",
           "Number of Planets in System": 1,
           "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 4.8,
           "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": null,
           "Planet Density [g": {
              "cm**3]": null
           },
           "Distance [pc]": 76.39,
           "Effective Temperature [K]": 4813,
           "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
        },
         {
           "rowid": 4,
           "Host name": "14 Her",
           "Number of Planets in System": 1,
           "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 4.64,
           "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": null,
           "Planet Density [g": {
              "cm**3]": null
           },
           "Distance [pc]": 18.15,
           "Effective Temperature [K]": 5311,
           "Date of Last Update": "5/14/2014"
        }];
var distance;
var planetRadius;

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

   distance= arr[i]["Distance [pc]"];
   planetRadius=arr[i]["Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]"];//This is the idea how we should access the json objects, as your operations are not clear to us just I'm giving the idea
  // Do what ever you want with  individual object
       if(planetRadius !== null){
           // If planet radius not null do whatever you want.
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I'm having trouble implementing it though.  This line right from my code right here " r: parseFloat(document.getElementById("new-r").value)" decides where the planet is situated. How would the distance variable you wrote need to replace it? Simply copying your code into my JSfiddle has no effect. Could you update my JSfiddle with the answer? https://jsfiddle.net/zxfqLsc9/

Comment: Do you wanna access "r" ?? from  " r: parseFloat(document.getElementById("new-r").value)"

Comment: Well, now that I think about it that function is obsolete. The code as it is now is so that you can add planets freely around the sun, but I don't want choice involved anymore. There are 4 planets in the array, I want those planets be automatically added from when the page is loaded. So that when I add a fifth planet into the array, the solar system is dynamically updated with that planet, which position and size is dependant on your distance and planetRadius variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write code for you, but I'm going to give you hints how to.

**First problem - fitting on the screen**: find the farthest edge from the center point, and then convert all distances so that they fit within that distance, but maintain relative distances accurately. For this, you need 3 input numbers and what you are finding:

- R'max = distance to the farthest edge on the screen (possibly in pixels).
- D'max = distance to the farthest planet in your json from sun.
- D'planet = distance which you want to convert into the relative distance.
- R'planet = distance to planet on the screen which you need to find (possibly in pixels).

Formula:

```
R'planet = D'planet / (R'max / D'max);
```

**Second problem - place planet on the screen**: you need planet's distance from sun on the screen (R'planet - you have it from previous step), as well as angle from sun (0 - 360 degrees - you said you can do random). Then you can calculate the screen coordinates like this:

- R'planet - distance on the screen.
- A'planet - screen angle from sun.
- X'planet - X coordinate of planet (assuming sun is at [0,0]).
- Y'planet - Y coordinate of planet (assuming sun is at [0,0]).

Formula:

```
X'planet = cos(A'planet) / R'planet;
Y'planet = sin(A'planet) / R'planet;
```

Remember that these coordinates are true if sun is at [0,0]. So, to place the planet on the screen, you need to add X'planet to the X'sun, and add Y'planet to Y'sun.

**Third problem - size of the planet on the screen**: again, similar to the first problem above, just decide what's the max planet size on the screen, and then divide the actual sizes by the ratio again.

```
Radius'screen = Radius'actual / (Radius'actualmax / Radius'maxpx);
```

There are many ways to draw it, either svg or just place div's with planet image in it and size accordingly.

This should be it.